# Facebook Android SDK, prompt user authentication to switch sessions

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, logout

This is kinda hard to explain. I'm building an application on android which is supposed to be used in a meeting in like a "stand" so people would submit some feedback after the meeting. Please notice there's a bunch of people who is going to use this application on the same device.

The application is gonna be used from different users on the same device and all of them are supposed to login with their Facebook account before continuing. For security reasons, I would love to have a way to distroy a Facebook session after a poll is submitted or simply, every time a new poll is issued, when the user is requiered to login on Facebook, I would like to force Facebook to prompt an authentication dialog (username and password again) even though there's an active session.

I've looked everywhere and I have found nothing. I know there's a way to request on Facebook a extensed permission to logout, but please notice this permission needs to be approved after logging in, so if a user, after logging in, just decide not to approve this permission, this session is going to be there until a browser is opened and a logout is performed from the Facebook site.

I've also thought on destroying a browser cookies but I don't know if is there such a permission on the android SDK to perform this.

Please, if any body has any idea on to get rid of this issue, I would really appreciate any suggestion or work around.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do this with the [Facebook SDK for Android 3.0 (beta)](https://developers.facebook.com/android/).

You can turn off SSO (by using the [SUPPRESS_SSO behavior](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/SessionLoginBehavior#SUPPRESS_SSO)) which should bring up a web dialog every time. And once the user is done interacting with your app, you can just call session.[closeAndClearTokenInformation()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Session#closeAndClearTokenInformation%28%29)

Cookies are not preserved when using the dialog login.

Comment: The `Session` class has been deprecated in the latest SDK version. Any alternatives?